# How to vertically align text field with it's label and button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm basically trying to have this kind of layout:

Label TextField Button

So e.g:
Number of copies [5 ] [Add]

Thought that would be really simple to do. But I've struggled for a few hours now, and this is the closest I've come, which is absolutely terrible:
[image: Bad attempt]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="numberOfCopies">Number of copies</label>
                    <input size="1" type="text" class="form-control" id="numberOfCopies">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first some Bootstrap-Basics:

- your 'row-div' should be wrapped by a 'container-div'
- `row` and `col-xx-x` classes need to be on their own div-tags

---

as you can see at the example below, you could easily get this done using css.

- With `display: flex;` we get all elements of the form-group side by side.
- With `white-space: nowrap` we 'tell' the label to be shown as one-line only.
- Using the `margin`-tags we will get the elements to the right position.

> To learn more take a look at the documentations of [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
>
> I think the [usage of input-groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups) could be interesting, too. Feel free to ask per comment, if anything is unclear.

```css
.form-group.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.form-group.flex label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.form-group.flex input {
  margin: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="form-inline pull-right">
        <div class="form-group flex">
          <label for="numberOfCopies">Number of copies</label>
          <input size="1" type="text" class="form-control" id="numberOfCopies">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```